# Toolbar is covering up the Statusbar

Tags: codenameone

I have a wierd situation where the app toolbar is blocking the view of the status bar. As you can see from the attachment, the toolbar sidemenu is at the top corner when it should be a little down to allow more space for the status bar.[image]

Comment: if you are using Auto Layout, you should constrain the top of the view to [topLayoutGuide](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621367-toplayoutguide) otherwise you need to work out the status bar height and deduct from the view's frame

Comment: Is this the iphone6+ skin? If so try updating the skin.

Answer (score 0):

Did you override `createStatusBar` or define the `StatusBar` UIID with something?

Comment: No i didnt override createStatusBar also I didnt define the StatusBar or Statusbar UIIDs in my app

Comment: I have updated the skin but same result and I also tested this app on the iphone6 s plus and the statusbar flows over the toolbar.

Comment: Did you use the `getTitleArea()` method or similar methods? Does your theme derive from the native iOS theme the `includeNativeBool` flag in the constants?